# How should I choose a media type for a FreeBSD installation?

Tags: freebsd, freenas

I use FreeNAS for my NAS server.  I was thinking of replacing it with a raw FreeBSD installation for a bit more flexibility (add a web server and possibly other things).  The following is an excerpt from the FreeNAS docs ([link](http://doc.freenas.org/index.php/Hardware_Recommendations#Compact_or_USB_Flash)):

> The FreeNAS® operating system is a running image. This means that it should not be installed onto a hard drive, but rather to a USB or compact flash device that is at least 2 GB in size. If you don't have compact flash, you can instead use a USB thumb drive that is dedicated to the running image and which stays inserted in the USB slot. While technically you can install FreeNAS® onto a hard drive, this is discouraged as you will lose the storage capacity of the drive. In other words, the operating system will take over the drive and will not allow you to store data on it, regardless of the size of the drive.

When I built my NAS server I didn't question this.  I installed FreeNAS on a USB stick as recommended.  Now that I'm looking to move to FreeBSD I was expecting to find a similar recommendation somewhere since FreeNAS is based on FreeBSD, but I have not found it.

**What medium should be used for a FreeBSD installation for a server?**

If you answer anything except "A USB stick" please elaborate why FreeNAS recommends using a USB stick but FreeBSD does not.

Answer (score 1):

[FreeNAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeNAS) is a specific utility/solution using FreeBSD as it's base OS, [FreeBSD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeBSD) is a general purpose operating system.

Since FreeNAS is a specific solution, the size of the OS is pretty static, where as with a general purpose OS you'll be adding and removing parts and data as required, so it's hard to guess how much space you'll need at any given time.

You can install FreeBSD on whatever type of drive you feel suits your needs best.  Generally OSs get installed on a HDD or SSD, but it really depends on your needs and wants, which only you know. ;)

Comment: I realize I can install the OS's on any media I want.  I was going to put in my question "Please don't tell me I can install FreeNAS/FreeBSD on any media I want" but I decided not to.  I can see now that I should have.  Additionally this doesn't answer any part of my question.

Comment: Regarding your edit, I don't think that is true.  With the FreeBSD jail system (which FreeNAS also uses) I can install any FreeBSD software I want to FreeNAS.  The size of my install could fluctuate greatly.

Comment: @ubiquibacon how does this _not_ answer your question? Q: "What's the recommended medium?" A: "Anything you like".

Comment: @terdon Q: "What's the recommended saw for cutting down a tree?" A: "Any saw you like"

Comment: @ubiquibacon the difference is that in this case there _is_ no recommended way. You can do whatever fits your needs best. FreeNAS has a specific requirement, FreeBSD does not as explained in techie's answer.

Comment: @terdon techie007's explanation of why FreeNAS recommends using a USB stick doesn't seem correct as I mentioned in my comment about the FreeNAS/FreeBSD jail system.  His explanation **may** end up being correct, but as of right now he has yet to offer any acceptable edit or counter comment to invalidate my comment or bolster his original answer.

Comment: @ubiquibacon Perhaps because his answer is already fine? If you are primarily interested in why FreeNAS recommends a USB stick, please [edit] your question to reflect that. As it stands, this is a perfectly good answer to your stated question.

Comment: @terdon No need to edit, I included what I wanted in my original question: *If you answer anything except "A USB stick" please **elaborate** why FreeNAS recommends using a USB stick but FreeBSD does not.*

Comment: Regarding your last sentence I would say that when I start using FreeBSD I will be removing/installing packages on occasion and running  a web server.  It isn't going to be my daily driver, but I will be writing to disk more than I do with FreeNAS.  Are you considering how dynamic/static my use of an OS is as the largest contributing factor of what drive medium I use?